# Many to Many relationship on Account Entity to Payment Methods, along with One To One relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to do the following in EF Core, but I am struggling in getting both relationships working at the same time.:

Account, many to many relationship with PaymentMethod.

```
class Account
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public List<PaymentMethod> PaymentMethods{get;set;}

  public PaymentMethod UsersPreferredPaymentMethod {get;set;}
  public int UsersPreferredPaymentMethodId{get;set;}
}

class PaymentMethod
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public List<Account> Accounts {get;set;}

  public Account PreferredPaymentAccount {get;set;}
}
```

The many to many is fine, but the one I am struggling with is now adding on the relationship for the Users Preferred payment method. I want this to be able to load the correct single payment method that the user has stored in `UsersPreferredPaymentMethodId`.

I am trying to configure this relation like this:

```
            modelBuilder
                .Entity<Account>()
                .HasOne(x => x.UsersPreferredPaymentMethod )
                .WithOne(x => x.PreferredPaymentAccount)
                .HasForeignKey<Account>(x => x.UsersPreferredPaymentMethodId);
```

Which does not work.

At the minute, I am storing the PreferredPaymentMethodId in `UsersPreferredPaymentMethodId` which is just an int field, but is not linked to anything, I could get random data in here which I don't want, I want it to be a FK to PaymentMethod and EF to load this PreferredPaymentMethod automatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this now for anyone that comes across it, you just need to make the FK nullable!

```
public int? UsersPreferredPaymentMethodId {get;set;}
```